# Trying to find matching font or just better idea for logo modification

Tags: fonts, logo

I'm designing logo for the first time, and trying to match a text for existing logo icon, however I am having trouble finding a font to suit. I have tried many sites but can't orientate which one fits to it.

I've stayed on this one at the end but would like to know your opinion. Also I know that the whole look of the logo is not fine, so you will help me a lot giving some ideas about better text position, etc...

(just one note. will be fine if text will be vertically middle of logo or equal to its height)[image]

Comment: Try using the W form you made as the basis for every letter. Capital E is a sideways-W. Capital V is half a W (in some languages a W is called double-V), an N is a V with a leg. You'd have a logo instead of a pic and a word. This would be in keeping with weaving, if that is the brand (guessing).

Comment: Thanks for answer. In this case I'll not use font right? the problem is that my client wants separate word with font not just image.

Comment: Bear in mind the client is usually wrong and probably has an accounting degree. You should sketch out a number of ideas. Pick some that meet the client's specific requests and pick the one(s) you think are best. If you really like one over the others, maybe work it up slightly more than the rest to draw them to it, but don't go all in until there is a decision.

Answer (score 1):

When creating logos you usually want the font to match the logo icon. In your case the logo icon has a very modern look to it so you should use a font with a similar style. Also, you should try typing "Weven" in all uppercase letters. I would recommend trying some of of the following fonts.

Raleway: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/raleway (I recommend ExtraBold)

Titillium: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Titillium (I recommend Bold)

Overall I recommend using bold fonts and uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to customize the whole set of the letters you can use an either bolder or thinner typeface.

Here's a handy and simple example:
[image: logo example]